# What does BS white sign means and why it destroys HTML DOM?

Tags: html, dom, whitespace

There is a BS sign on the beginning of my HTML document, and when it's there it destroys HTML DOM (looked up in Chrome and FF console) by moving all tags from `<head></head>` to `<body></body>`.

My question - what is it and why it behave like that?

View from Notepad++ with all white signs visible.
[image]

View from Chrome -> Console -> Elements
[image]

Comment: The "BS" symbol is a backspace (which literally means to move back one character, not to also delete it).

Comment: Try changing encoding from "UTF-8" to "UTF-8 Without BOM"

Comment: For anyone to reproduce this in their browser: `data:text/html,%08<!doctype html><head><meta charset=utf-8><title>My page</title><body><p>`

Comment: @Justinas: The backspace character is not a BOM.